# Is there a formal version of "he's the real thing"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, formality

Is there a formal version of "he's the real thing"?

As in:

> - Man, she's really good at tennis!
> - She plays national. She's the real thing.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds pretty formal in this case:

> - She plays national. She's an authentic athlete.
> - She plays national. She's an accomplished tennis player.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a dozen different formal or almost formal versions, e.g.:

> X is a world-class tennis player.
>   X plays tennis at the professional level.
>   X is a top-level tennis player.

I think you probably get the idea.